# How does one make Python objects hashable when there is nothing to distinguish them?

Tags: python, hash, set

Let's say I want to use a set() to store a bunch of objects whose only distinction is that they exist and are not other instances of the same class. Otherwise, they are not distinguishable, e.g., no `def __eq__(self, other): return self.qux == other.qux`, because that `qux` is the same (or random) for all of them. How do you define an `__eq__` and `__hash__` function for that class?

Comment: can you show some example data please

Comment: Have you tried storing your objects in a `set()`? What happened?

Comment: What would be the hashing criteria of the objects? When these instances should be considered the same so that the set keeps only one of them?

Comment: `object.__eq__` already returns `False` for any two distinct objects, and `object.__hash__` is unique for any two distinct objects. You don't have to define `__eq__` or `__hash__` at all; you are describing the default behavior of an arbitrary `object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to implement either `__eq__` *or* `__hash__`.

> User-defined classes have `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` methods by
>   default; with them, all objects compare unequal (except with
>   themselves) and `x.__hash__()` returns an appropriate value such that
>   `x == y` implies both that `x is y` and `hash(x) == hash(y)`.

Source: [Data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

The default is something like:

```
class OnlyExists:

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self)
```

Because it's unequal to everything, instances can only be found by identity. Giving a minimal hash implementation (i.e. not just returning the same hash value for every instance) means that the instances don't all end up in the same "bucket", which would be a catastrophic collision and mean all dictionary/set searches fall to `O(n)`.

```
>>> class OnlyExists:
...     pass
...
>>> a = OnlyExists()
>>> b = OnlyExists()
>>> s = {a, b}
>>> len(s)
2
>>> a in s
True
>>> b in s
True
>>> OnlyExists() in s
False
```

Comment: Just thought the fact that the inherited methods are sufficient should be emphasized.